# Walletnotify hits twice, immediately

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, wallet-notify

So I've read most of what is tagged with walletnotify, but haven't found a solution. I know walletnotify is supposed to run twice, one for the unconfirmed transaction and again, when it reaches 1 confirmation. For me, it runs twice, right off the bat.

bitcoin.conf:

```
server=1
daemon=1

maxconnections=12
maxuploadtarget=20
rpcuser=xxxx
rpcpassword=xxxx
testnet=1
rpcallowip=52.86.xx.xx
walletnotify=/home/scripts/transaction.sh %s
keypool=10000
```

transaction.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
F=notify_log
D=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
echo ${D} - ${1} >> ${F}
```

Produces an output of:

```
20180126015435 - cf59f4c18a80773164c7efdf2a77722099722b3a61274f940aea52cbd600db2b
20180126015435 - cf59f4c18a80773164c7efdf2a77722099722b3a61274f940aea52cbd600db2b
```

Same TXID, same timestamp. But why twice?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.  on the mainnet I get the events about 10min apart (as expected), but in testnet they come in at the same time i.e. after 1 confirmation (about 30min)

Comment: I would love to help but it's too long ago and I don't remember, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

walletnotify will execute every time you either

```
1.receive bitcoin
2.send bitcoin
3.when a bitcoin gets its first confirmation.
```

@Dawg are you transfer payment in your wallet it self ?
if yes then OK , if not try to send/receive the payments from other bitcoin node then you can observe clearly ,Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
#!/bin/bash
F=/home/btcdev/wallet_transaction_log
D=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
echo ${D} - ${1} >> ${F}
```

Ref: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=203438.0